# Prove that there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of three cubes

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of three cubes.
I thought this involved looking at cubes mod 7 but that doesn't work as they can be 0,+-1 so you can make any number mod7..... ok same thing different story for mod9.

Can this be solved using Fermat's little theorem?
X^6is congruent to 1 mod 7
express the three cubes as (X^2)^3.

No actually this doesn't work as this is just the same as the method for working mod9 on the cubes, with out the negative for squared, and also I think that Fermat's little theorem assumes that x is not a multiple of 7.

Comment: Hint: try mod 9

Comment: Don't read this unless you've completely given in, as it just gives you the answer: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/.

Comment: is there any way of doing this with fermats little theorem??

Comment: Thanks, in art and craft of problem solving Paul Zeitz instructor Manuel it says to use mod7

Answer (score 3):

Any number $m\equiv\pm4\pmod9$ cannot be expressed as a sum of $3$ cubes:

- $n\equiv0\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv0^3\equiv 0\pmod9$
- $n\equiv1\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv1^3\equiv+1\pmod9$
- $n\equiv2\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv2^3\equiv-1\pmod9$
- $n\equiv3\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv3^3\equiv 0\pmod9$
- $n\equiv4\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv4^3\equiv+1\pmod9$
- $n\equiv5\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv5^3\equiv-1\pmod9$
- $n\equiv6\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv6^3\equiv 0\pmod9$
- $n\equiv7\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv7^3\equiv+1\pmod9$
- $n\equiv8\pmod9 \implies n^3\equiv8^3\equiv-1\pmod9$

No $3$ values chosen from $\{0,+1,-1\}$ will ever sum up to $\pm4\pmod9$.

Comment: It seems that only the multiples of $9$ work as a modulus for this argument!

Comment: the multiples of 9 work because if you multiply the results above by any integer, then as 9 isn't prime they will all be distinct or there will be some repeats mod9, so there will be less or equal to 4 different results mod 9

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you simplify this and leave out the $8$s? Just $\{0, \pm1\}$.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: Hmmmmm... I was about to say no, but with $3$ terms... **Yes You Can** (although, I admit that saying it today is a somewhat ironic).

Comment: @ColmBhandal: Improved accordingly, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix M and see the integers in the interval 
[0, M^3 - 1]

M^3 integers, as the sum of 3 cubes  we can present not more when M (3 equal cubes) + M*(M-1) (2*a^3 + b^3 - sum for ab) + M(M-1)(M-2)/6 (3 distinct numbers)

M^3 - M - M(M-1) - M(M-1)(M-2)/6 -> +inf with  M -> +inf