# infinite amount of integers that can't be written as the sum of two cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that there are an  infinite number of integers that can't be written as the sum of two cubes .

I tried to consider integers in the form of $10^{3n+1}$  but I feel there is something wrong with this approach .

Comment: A stronger result is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005205/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-numbers-that-cannot-be-expressed-as-the-sum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n = a^3 + b^3$ for some integers $a, b$. Then, the only possible residues $\mod 7$ of $n$ are $0, 1, -1, 2, -2$, in view of the fact that the cubes $\mod 7$ belong in the residue class of $0, 1$ or $-1$. This is easy to verify.

Now, if $n \not\equiv 0, 1, -1, 2, -2 \mod 7$, it follows that $n$ is not representable as the sum of 2 cubes. There are infinitely many such $n$.